# How to fit text on Button?

Tags: android, button, text

In my android app I have a Button for voting photos. When the user select this Button, the text on this Button became "Thanks for your vote" and when he see a photo that he voted before, on Button will see the text "you have already vote for this photo"...the problem is that it looks like this : http://i55.tinypic.com/t4z3vl.png

Can anyone help me hot can I fit the text on Button?

Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

In xml I have this :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/imagetitle"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Previous" android:id="@+id/previous" />
        <Button android:layout_width="185dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vote for this picture" android:id="@+id/vote" />
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Next" android:id="@+id/next" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you want to do? let it take more space? or clip text?

Comment: I want that the button for voting to be on the same level and on the same line as button Next and Previous...and to see all the text clear on button

Comment: for second button use **android:width** directly and android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you want to align the top of all buttons 
add this line in your layout

```
LinearLayout android:baselineAligned="false"
```

Comment: If I have this : http://i52.tinypic.com/ifa987.jpg I get this :http://i53.tinypic.com/2wbt121.png So,it is better,but not ok

Comment: @Gabrielle  assign layout weight to them might help u

Answer (score 3):

Use `"wrap_content"` for the `layout_height` property of the `Button`

Comment: I have wrap_content for layout_height

Answer (score 1):

Hi take a look at these http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html maybe if you have deferent styles for each screen it will solve your problem. :D