# Android button text out of border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

After looking in google and in the from for set boundaries to fit text in `RelativeLayout` to the button size.

- [Android Button layout with big text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786948/android-button-layout-with-big-text-size) didn't help
- [How to fit text on Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897878/how-to-fit-text-on-button) didn't help
- [How does setting baselineAligned to false improve performance in LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319916/how-does-setting-baselinealigned-to-false-improve-performance-in-linearlayout) I am on Relative

example from my app:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2wec9d5&s=8#.VUZns_lVhBc

My xml button:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_game"
    tools:context=".ClassicMode" >
    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numOfGuesses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gallery1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guesses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/guesses"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="60px" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="226dp"
            android:layout_height="152dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:src="@drawable/argentina" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="check"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="check"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="check"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="check"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scorenum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="60px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scorenum"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/score"
        android:textSize="60px" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hint"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="hint"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting following properties on your buttons:

```
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:singleLine="false" // set this to true if you want your text to be single line
                           // or to false otherwise
```

And I suggest removing this line from your buttons:

> ```
> android:layout_alignLeft="some_button_id"
> ```

Comment: still it goes out of bounderis but a littel bit better i think just one word going out

Comment: @Adi Could you paste here another screenshot and point out which buttons goes out of scope?

Comment: @Adi Actually when I paste your code into my editor - it looks fine. No adjustments needed. Are you sure you're not changing your buttons style from code?

Comment: ive changed what you told me to change or to add as layoutMarginiLeft/Right i didnt touch the style i mean